# Деплой сервлета вручную на Tomcat: NotFound

Tags: java, servlet, tomcat, развертывание

Создал простой сервлет:

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

public class InfoServlet extends GenericServlet {

    private ServletConfig sc;

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
        sc = config;
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse) throws ServletException, IOException {
        servletResponse.setContentType("text/html; charset=windows-1251");

        PrintWriter pw = servletResponse.getWriter();

        pw.println("<html><head>");
        pw.println("<title>Servlets parameters</title>");
        pw.println("</head><body><h2>Servlets Info</h2>");

        pw.println("Servlet name - " + sc.getServletName() + "<br>");
        pw.println("Servlet params: <br>");

        Enumeration names = sc.getInitParameterNames();

        while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
            String name = (String) names.nextElement();
            pw.println(name + ": ");
            pw.println(sc.getInitParameter(name) + "<br>");
        }

        pw.println("</body></html>");
        pw.flush();
        pw.close();

    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        sc = null;
    }
}
```

Откомпилировал его, получил соответствующий файл `InfoServlet.class`

Создал конфигурационный файл `web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1"
         metadata-complete="true">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>InfoServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/info</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>



    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>txt</extension>
        <mime-type>text/plain</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>
    <mime-mapping>
        <extension>html</extension>
        <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
    </mime-mapping>

</web-app>
```

`web.xml` закидываю в папку `%TOMCAT_FOLDER%/webapps/ivansm/WEB-INF`
`InfoServlet.class` закидываю в папку `%TOMCAT_FOLDER%/webapps/ivansm/WEB-INF/classes`

Запускаю Tomcat. Перехожу по адресу `localhost:8080/ivansm/info`, ожидаю увидеть собранную в сервлете, однако в итоге получаю `404 - Not Found`.

Вопрос: что делаю неправильно, как исправить?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: исправил в файле web.xml тэг `<web-app ...>` на `<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="2.5">`. Видимо, источник был устаревшим

Comment: Попробовал ваш код запустить, как есть - и всё заработало. Возможно, у вас версия Томката несвежая, которая Servlet 3.1 не поддерживает